# js-yaml -> Parse ruby types

Tags: javascript, ruby, yaml

I am making a Ruby console in JavaScript and thus need to accurately send Ruby object information to the renderer process. I decided to use YAML given that it is super easy to use YAML on the Ruby side and contains all information required. But I keep getting errors.

Take the following ruby:

```
[Test,Test.new].to_yaml
```

This converts to the following YAML:

```
---
- !ruby/class 'Test'
- !ruby/object:Test {}
```

When I try to parse this with [`JS-YAML`](https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/) we get the following error:

```
unknown tag !<!ruby/class> at line 2, column 21:
    - !ruby/class 'Test'
                        ^
```

So I expect this is happenning because YAML in JavaScript doesn't have Ruby types! I've seen that one solution is to create new YAML types to handle this data:

```
var RubyClassType = new jsyaml.Type('!ruby/class', {
  kind: 'class'
});
```

However, in an ideal world I wouldn't have to define each individual type. In an ideal world either, all unknown types will be treated the same (e.g. as yaml sequences) or ruby wouldn't generate the odd ruby types in the first place. Can I get around this issue without having to define every Ruby type in JavaScript?

Comment: @engineermnky I initially started out using JSON but it has some massive issues. E.G. inability to differentiate between symbols and text, inability to have objects as keys of an object, ... These can be overcome, it involves building a new JSON parsing system or a new JSON dump system which is quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be handled in JS-YAML as follows: [handle_unknown_types.js](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/master/examples/handle_unknown_types.js)

Won't accept this as an answer though as a ruby-first solution would be better.